# Given a function $f:N\rightarrow N$ it is true that $f(1)=43$, $f(2)=142$ and $f(n+1)=3f(n)+f(n-1)$, $n\ge 2$. Prove that $(f(n+1), f(n))=1$

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, solution-verification, contest-math, problem-solving

Given a function $f:N\rightarrow N$ it is true  that $f(1)=43$, $f(2)=142$ and $f(n+1)=3f(n)+f(n-1)$, $n\ge 2$. Prove that $\frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)}$ is irreducible.

I proved it as follows:

If $n=1$ it holds true.

I assume that it holds true for $n\le k$

$f(k+2)=3f(k+1)+f(k)$

$\frac{f(k+2)}{f(k+1)}=3+\frac{f(k)}{f(k+1)}$

Since from the assumption $\frac{f(k)}{f(k+1)}$ is irreducible, hence $\frac{f(k+2)}{f(k+1)}$ is irreducible, hence we have proved it using full induction.

Could you please look at my solution and confirm it is correct and provide other neat solutions for this question?

Comment: It's good.  I was a little worried you would need two base cases and your induction step might tacitly be assume $n \ge 2$ (in the uses of the recursive definition) which are two very common mistakes but it seems that's not actually a worry in this case.

Comment: @fleablood thank you very much:) Have a great day